# How to directly read a line which has the maximum tab delimiters in the tab delimited source file

Tags: c#, parsing, split, csv

Currently i am reading the tab delimited file line by line, splitting the items in each line and looking for the tab delimited line with 50 items by hard coding value 50 and then create the 
data table.

Issues: Faced - tab delimited source files has tab delimited lines sometimes with 50 or 53 items after splitting. Need to directly read a line which has the maximum tab delimiters in the tab delimited source file and then continue with my logic.

My C# code

```
using (var sr = new StreamReader(sourceFileFullName))
{
  string line = null;
  while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
  {
    var items = line.Split(new[] { '\t', '\n' }).ToArray();

    if (items.Length != 50)
    continue;
  //Rest of my code to create datatable for the items after splitting in tab delimitedline
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the below snippet

```
string content = "";
using (var reader = new StreamReader("C:\\temp\\abc.txt"))
{
    content = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(content))
{
    var value = content.Split('\n').OrderByDescending(y => y.Split('\t').Count()).Take(1);
}
```

Comment: @ sprinter The variable value is pointing to the line based on the string content. Now i need to continue reading line by line from now and split and add in the datatable.